# IOS device Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server

Tags: nginx, webpack, webpack-dev-server

- Operating System: OSX
- Node: 8.4.0
- NPM: 5.3.0
- webpack: ^3.8.1
- webpack-dev-server: ^2.9.4

#### webpack.config.js

```
const join = (modulePath) => path.join(process.cwd(), modulePath);
const port = 3000;

let config = {
  entry: {
    app: join('app')
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: join('dist'),
    pathinfo: true,
    publicPath: `http://localhost:${port}`
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './app',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline: true,
    port,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['es2015'],
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist', 'build'], {
      root: process.cwd()
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html'
    })
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

nginx reverse proxy config

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  www.domain1.com;
        error_page 500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
        location /srilanka/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        }
    }
```

hosts

```
127.0.0.1 www.domain1.com
```

I use `nginx` reverse proxy + `webpack-dev-server`

For IOS devices, it throw an error:

`Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server http://localhost:3000/app.js`

**PC and android device works fine.**

#### Expected Behavior

use IOS device access website should works fine.

#### Actual Behavior

I use IOS device safari web inspector find this error.
[image]

I create an repo, so you can reproduce this behavior easily 
https://github.com/mrdulin/webpack-dev-server